# Interpreting result of Inequality

Tags: inequality, lambert-w

I am faced with the following inequality:

$$3\sqrt{3}\cdot\sqrt[3]{4}^h > 4\pi h^2$$

After running it through Wolfram, I get the following inequality:

$$x>-\frac{3W_{-1}\big(-\frac{ln(2)}{2\sqrt[4]{3}\sqrt{\pi}}\big)}{ln(2)}$$

I'm not at all familiar with the Lambert-$W$ function, so I would appreciate some sort of explanation as to what this result means. I am mainly concerned about what this means about the possible values of $x$ (i.e. can the inequality be satisfied with $x\in \mathbb{R}$?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Without Lambert function.***

Consider the problem as $$\frac{3 \sqrt{3}\, 2^{2 h/3} }{4\pi h^2} >1$$ and taking logarithms $$\log\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{3}\, 2^{2 h/3} }{4\pi h^2}  \right)>0$$ Expanding the logarithm (assuming $h>0$, consider the function $$f(h)=\log\left(\frac{3 \sqrt{3} }{4\pi }  \right)+\frac{2h}3\log(2)-2\log(h)$$ and its derivatives $$f'(h)=\frac{2}3\log(2)-\frac 2h\qquad \qquad f''(h)=\frac 2{h^2}>0 $$ The first derivative cancels for $$h_*=\frac{3}{\log (2)}\approx 4.32809\implies f(h_*)=\log \left(\frac{2^{\frac{2}{\log (2)}-2} \log ^2(2)}{\sqrt{3} \pi }\right)\approx -1.81336$$ and then there are two values of $h$ which make $f(h)=0$.

We can compute these roots using Newton method. The iterates would then be

- for the first root

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & h_n \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0.726245 \\
 2 & 0.766487 \\
 3 & 0.767866 \\
 4 & 0.767868
\end{array}
\right)$$ then $h_1\approx 0.767868$.

- for the second root

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & h_n \\
 0 & 10 \\
 1 & 13.3090 \\
 2 & 13.0201 \\
 3 & 13.0186
\end{array}
\right)$$ then $h_2\approx 13.0186$.

So $f(h)<0$ if $h_1< h < h_2$.

***With Lambert function.***

What Wolfram Alpha gave you as a result is the analytical expression of $h_2$ but, if you plot the function, you will notice that one part is missing $(0 < h < h_1)$.

In fact, the equation has three roots which write
$$h_0=-\frac{3 W\left(\frac{\log (2)}{2 \sqrt[4]{3} \sqrt{\pi }}\right)}{\log (2)}\approx -0.564418$$ 
$$h_1=-\frac{3 W\left(-\frac{\log (2)}{2 \sqrt[4]{3} \sqrt{\pi }}\right)}{\log (2)}\approx 0.767868$$
$$h_2=-\frac{3 W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log (2)}{2 \sqrt[4]{3} \sqrt{\pi }}\right)}{\log (2)}\approx 13.0186$$ and for $h_0 < h < h_1$, $f(h) >0$ also.

**Edit**

Considering the small portion around $h=0$, you could notice that, using Taylor series for the orginal expression, we would get 
$$3\sqrt{3}\cdot\sqrt[3]{4}^h - 4\pi h^2=3 \sqrt{3}+2 \sqrt{3}  \log (2)\,h)+ \left(\frac{2 \log ^2(2)}{\sqrt{3}}-4 \pi
   \right)h^2+O\left(h^3\right)$$ Ignoring the higher order terms, the roots of the quadratic are
$$\frac{ 3 \left(\pm\sqrt{12 \sqrt{3} \pi -3 \log ^2(2)}+\sqrt{3} \log (2)\right)}{2
   \left(6 \pi -\sqrt{3} \log ^2(2)\right)}$$ that is to say $\approx -0.565320$ and $\approx 0.765221$ to be compared with the exact values of $h_0$ and $h_1$. Between these two roots, the function is positive.

If, using Wolfram Alpha, you type

```
    sqrt(3) (4^(1/3))^h-4 pi h^2 > 0
```

it gives you a range in terms of two Lambert functions

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. If I'm interpreting this correctly, the inequality holds for when $h$ is near 0, or if it's larger than 13.0186?

Comment: @高田航. Yes, if $h$ must be positve it gas to be between  $0$ and $h_1$ or above $h_2$.

Comment: I see, thanks for your help.

Comment: @高田航. I added a few things about the approximation using Taylor series and the results looks quite "funny". By the way, if you consider that my answer is a good answer, may be you could accept it.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to accept it, my apologies.